# Adding google fonts to WordPress theme

Tags: theme-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, fonts, autoloading

I am trying to add google fonts to a custom WordPress theme. Therefore I tried to enqueue selected three font faces at once to make it fast loading. So, I use the below codes to register and enqueue the same.

```
wp_register_style('googlFonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,700&family=DM+Serif+Display&family=La+Belle+Aurore&display=swap');
wp_enqueue_style('googlFonts');
```

When I search via source code I can only see the last font. Other fonts are not loading. Even I can't see the same complete URL in the source code. Below is what I saw from the source code.
[image]

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're probably running into this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/new-google-fonts-url-incompatible-with-wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: @JacobPeattie The answer was there. Thank you. Appreciate it.

Comment: @user2584538 I thought you should know that there's also a [note](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_style/#comment-5464) on the documentation for `wp_register_style()` ([and also `wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/#comment-5463)).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove version parameter.

```
wp_register_style('googlFonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,700&family=DM+Serif+Display&family=La+Belle+Aurore&display=swap', array(), null);
wp_enqueue_style('googlFonts');
```